# Using getInitialProps gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've seen many questions relating to issues with `getInitialProps` and `getStaticProps` but haven't been able to solve my own.

I'm merely trying to load some json data (I console.logged it and know it's not undefined) and pass it to my `Main` component:

```
import Card from "./components/Card";
import data from "../data/data.json";

const Main = ({ cards }) => {
  return (
      <div}>
        {cards.map((card) => {
          <Card key={card.id} card={card} />;
        })}
      </div>

  );
};

Main.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  return {
    props: { cards: data },
  };
};

export default Main;
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I tried with `getStaticProps` as well, same issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You omitted where `data` comes from, I assume for simplicity. Make sure it is actually an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) this should work:

```js
import Card from "./components/Card";
import data from "../data/data.json";

const Main = ({ cards }) => {
  return (
      <div}>
        {cards.map((card) => {
          <Card key={card.id} card={card} />;
        })}
      </div>

  );
};

Main.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  // await for `data`

  return {
    cards: data,
  };
  // ^-- note the change, you nested your object inside a `props` property
};

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.url.com')
  const json = await res.json()
  return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
}
```

you have to change this

```
return {
    props: { cards: data },
  };
```

should use this:

```
return { cards: data  }
```

for more you look : [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)

Comment: How is your answer different to mine from two days earlier?